# Bash script to merge files in a directory and delete originals

Tags: bash

I'm writing a very small bash script to merge some files in a directory.

Say I have a directory full of files:

```
 deb_1
 deb_2
 deb_3
 deb_4
 ...
```

I want to write a small bash script to merge them all into a file, and delete the originals

So I would run, `mrg deb* outputfile`, and the resulting directory would look like:

```
 outputfile
```

Containing all of the deb files merged. The way I do it normally is `cat deb* > outputfile && rm deb* -f`

However trying to convert this to a bash script doesn't quite work out:

```
 #!bin/bash
 cat $1 > $2 && rm $1 -f
```

The wildcard expansion replaces `$1-> deb_1,$2-> deb_2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your script as is:

```
#!bin/bash
cat $1 > $2 && rm $1 -f
```

But apply single quotes to the first argument when calling it:

```
bash myscript.sh 'deb*' outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to avoid doing that?

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs: you could try passing the `outputfile` as the first argument and considering the rest of parameters received in the script as the input files (by looping through `$@`). In this case, you must not quote the wildcard pattern when calling `myscript.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Along the line that @Eugeniu mentioned in his comment, something like

```
$ myscript outputfile files*
```

would be possible, given the following definition of `myscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT="$1";shift
cat "$@" > "$OUTPUT" && rm "$@" -f
```

- `$@` is a list of all command line arguments,
- and `"$@"` is a list of separately-quoted command line arguments: `"deb01" "deb02" "deb03"`.
- `shift` is used to remove the output file from the list of parameters so that it does not appear in the expansion of `$@`.
- `cat` concatenates the files together into your ouput file,
- and `rm` removes the originals.

#### Usage

The general form of the command becomes:

```
myscript OUTPUT [INPUT_FILE]...
```

In your case, you'd want to call this as

```
$ myscript outputfile deb_{1..4}/*
```

which grabs every file inside of each directory as command line arguments to `myscript`

#### Alternate implementation

Using the last argument as the output file is probably possible (using `$#`), but requires more work to remove the last parameter from `$@`.

A simple way to overcome this — with the obvious modification to the script to use stdout — would be:

```
$ myscript input files... > outputfile
```

Since redirections are applied by the shell (truncating and opening `outputfile` for input) before the command is run, the `rm` would still be safe in exactly the same sense that it is now — which is questionable, IMO.